# PHP the code executes but nothing is inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a receival table that will store user's information. but the values do not get inserted into the database.
This is my connection to the database and sql statements to inserted the values the user will post.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="l3tme1N@123"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="shipping_pro"; // Database name  
$tbl_name="receiver"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot 
connect"); 
if(!$con){
die ('cannot connect to the server')
}
if (!mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con))
{
echo"no db selected";
}

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$cc = $_POST['cc'];
$sender = $_POST['sender-name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$tracker = $_POST['tracker'];
$code_phone = $_POST['code_phone'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$code_phone1 = $_POST['code_phone1'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];


$sql1="INSERT INTO 'receival' (name,idcard,sender-name,address,tracker, 
receiver-telnum, sender-telnum) VALUES  
('$name','$cc','$sender','$address', '$tracker', '$code_phone$phone', 
'$code_phone1$telefono')";
$result = mysql_query($con,$sql1);
} 
?>
```

the html codes

this is the form that i have created for take user input.

I have looked at most solutions here and on google but i still cannot find any solution

```
<form action="receive.php"  method="post" class="form-horizontal" data- 
parsley-validate novalidate >
<div class="form-group " id="gnombre">
<label for="office" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of Recipient</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control office" parsley-trigger="change" 
required name="name"  placeholder="Name of Recipient">
</div>                                  
</div>
<div class="form-group " id="gnombre">
<label for="officer_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $CEDULA; 
?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="number" class="form-control officer_name" parsley- 
trigger="change" required name="cc"  placeholder="<?php echo $numbercedula; ? 
>">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group " id="gnombre">
<label for="officer_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sender</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control officer_name" iparsley- 
trigger="change" required name="sender-name"  placeholder="Name of Sender">
</div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group" id="gapellido">
<label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control- 
label"><?php echo $direccion; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control address" parsley-trigger="change" 
required name="address"   placeholder="Receiver Address">
                                </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group" id="gapellido">
                                <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tracker Number</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                 <form name="form2" action="" method="">
                                                    <!--<strong><?php echo $codeproducto; ?></strong><br> -->
                                                    <input type="text" autofocus list="browsers" name="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required>
                                                    <datalist id="browsers">
                                                        <?php
                                                            $pa=mysql_query("SELECT tracking FROM  courier 
                                                            ");             
                                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
                                                                echo '<option value="'.$row['tracking'].'">';
                                                            }
                                                        ?> 
                                                    </datalist>

                                </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group" id="ptelefonos">
                                <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $telefono; ?></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select type="number" class="form-control ph_no" parsley-trigger="change" required name="code_phone" placeholder="<?php echo $telefonocustomer2; ?>">

                                        <option data-countrycode="GH" value="233">Ghana (+233)</option>

                                    </select>                                                                       
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control ph_no" parsley-trigger="change" required name="phone" placeholder="Receiver's Phone Number">   
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="form-group" id="ptelefonos">
                            <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $telefono; ?></label>                                
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select type="number" class="form-control ph_no" parsley-trigger="change" required name="code_phone1" placeholder="Sender's phone Number">

                                        <option data-countrycode="GH" value="233">Ghana (+233)</option>

                                    </select>                                                                       
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control ph_no" parsley-trigger="change" required name="telefono" placeholder="Sender's phone Number">
                                </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        <?php echo $cerrar; ?></button>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" name="save" type="submit"  id="submit" value="Save">
                       </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even do this is a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected error relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Anyway, where is the problem? Is your form sending data correctly? Check the request in your browser's network tools to see what values are sent. Is the server receiving the values properly? Do `var_dump($_POST);` to see what values are being submitted. Is your query succeeding? Check the value of `$result` - if it's `false` then your query failed, and you can use `echo mysql_error($con);` to get the error message. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php. You should learn how to debug your code in a similar manner to this, to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: `INSERT INTO 'receival'` should just be `INSERT INTO receival`?

Comment: in which table your inserting data is it `receiver` or `receival`

Comment: @sanojlawrence receival.. that was a wrong typo. i change that in the code but still nothing inserts into the database. thanks

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine In that case you need to carry out the debugging steps I outlined above. Just from the code above we do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: @ADyson i have began working on the debugging process using the steps you outlined above. Any challenges  will be notified. Thank you.

Comment: @ADyson i used PDO and finally got it done. During the debugging i found out that my column names had hyphens in them and that is why my query was not running. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , you need to replace 'receival' with receival  :

```
 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password="l3tme1N@123"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="shipping_pro"; // Database name  
$tbl_name="receiver"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot 
connect"); 
if(!$con){
die ('cannot connect to the server')
}
if (!mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con))
{
echo"no db selected";
}

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$cc = $_POST['cc'];
$sender = $_POST['sender-name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$tracker = $_POST['tracker'];
$code_phone = $_POST['code_phone'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$code_phone1 = $_POST['code_phone1'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];


$sql1="INSERT INTO receival (name,idcard,sender-name,address,tracker, 
receiver-telnum, sender-telnum) VALUES('$name','$cc','$sender','$address', '$tracker', '$code_phone$phone', 
'$code_phone1$telefono')";
$result = mysql_query($con,$sql1);
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has already been pointed out in comments that you have to use mysqli_* or PDO with prepared statements. So I will just look at your most trivial error (assuming it is the only one)

Your insert query has many errors: values are not correctly inserted and your table name is wrapped in quotes.
Change it to:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO receival (name,idcard,sender-name,address,tracker, 
receiver-telnum, sender-telnum) VALUES  
('$name','$cc','$sender','$address', '$tracker', '$code_phone.$phone', 
'$code_phone1.$telefono')";
```

This should fix it and make your insert work.